# Set UITextFieldDelegate & release after UITextField dealloc, self contained

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, delegates

I have created a class that implements `UITextFieldDelegate` so I only need to use `[MyDelegateClass setDelegate:textField someConfigparams:...]` in order to use it. Inside it will create an object and assign to the `textFieldDelegate`.

The problem appears when releasing: the `setDelegate` method in `UITextField` doesn't retain the object so I can't just autorelease it. I could keep a reference outside to release it but it is ugly and prone to error since I need to do an extra work outside the delegate class. Subclassing `UITextField` is a bad option since I would need to use always this subclass which could conflict with others.

Is there any way I could release the delegate object when `UITextField` object is destroyed without relying to code outside MyDelegateClass?

Answer (score 0):

I assume [MyDelegateClass setDelegate:textField someConfigparams:...] creates and instance of MyDelegateClass and assigns that instance as the delegate on the provided textField.  What i would do is make the instance of MyDelegateClass a singleton, meaning there is only ever 1 instance.

Basically what will happen in this case is that MyDelegateClass will retain a strong reference to a single static instance of itself and that instance will stay alive for as long as your application stays alive or until you purposefully release it.  It is perfectly ok to have one instance of an object be the delegate for many textFields.  The memory impact of having a single instance of this class alive always is going to be constant, i.e. not growing, and very small.

Comment: Yes, it creates a new object and assigns it as delegate.
The problem with it are the "configParameters" which modify the behaviour of the object, so a singleton is not an option since each instance is different.

Comment: Modify your object to handle multiple config params based on the textfield passed in.  You could use a dictionary and store the configparams based on the textfields tag.  This would avoid a possible retain cycle and still allow you to customize the behavior of the delegate on a per textfield basis.

Comment: It would become more or less the same since this config params would be unreleased and I wouldn't know when to release them. It would be moving the problem from one place to another but not solving it, adding some complexity and some reuse ability.